# Apache CXF slow to respond

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

We are in trouble to use of apache cxf.

We use 'Apache CXF 2.2.5' and 'Spring Framework 3.2.10'  for SOAP service in our system.

This is a brief diagram of our system 
( see below)

```
+--------+        +--------------+          +---------------------+   +----------------
| L4     |-- RB --| Apache Httpd |- mod_jk -| JBoss AS            |---| Spring Framework 3.2.10
| Switch |        | 2.2.27 (2EA) |          | 7.1.1 (2EA x 4INST) |   | Apache CXF 2.2.5 / JDK 7
+--------+        +--------------+          +---------------------+   +----------------
```

APM system tells us there is a response delay in our system because of one of the apache cxf method `ServletDestination.invoke()` when SOAP Messages are incoming about 100 TPS.

It is also reports `ServletDestination.invoke()` spent over 70 seconds per one transaction.

Our SIB(Service Implementation Bean) works fine (it spent below 1 seconds).

All of our systems OS parameter settings are good.

```
- open files max : 32767
- max processes : 300000
```

mod_jk settings are like below (per jboss instance)

```
- socket_keepalive=true
- socket_timeout=300
- connection_pool_size=500
- connection_pool_minsize=300
- connection_pool_timeout=60
```

● Source of `ServletDestination.invoke()` method, Apache CXF 2.2.5

```
public void invoke(final ServletConfig config,
                   final ServletContext context, 
                   final HttpServletRequest req, 
                   final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    MessageImpl inMessage = new MessageImpl();
    setupMessage(inMessage,
                 config,
                 context,
                 req,
                 resp);

    ExchangeImpl exchange = new ExchangeImpl();
    exchange.setInMessage(inMessage);
    exchange.setSession(new HTTPSession(req));
    inMessage.setDestination(this);

    incomingObserver.onMessage(inMessage);

}
```

● Source of `AbstractHTTPDestination.setupMessage()` method that is called in `ServletDestination.invoke()`, Apache CXF 2.2.5

```
protected void setupMessage(Message inMessage,
                            final ServletConfig config,
                            final ServletContext context, 
                            final HttpServletRequest req, 
                            final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    inMessage.setContent(InputStream.class, req.getInputStream());
    inMessage.put(HTTP_REQUEST, req);
    inMessage.put(HTTP_RESPONSE, resp);
    inMessage.put(HTTP_CONTEXT, context);
    inMessage.put(HTTP_CONFIG, config);

    inMessage.put(Message.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD, req.getMethod());
    inMessage.put(Message.REQUEST_URI, req.getRequestURI());
    String contextPath = req.getContextPath();
    if (contextPath == null) {
        contextPath = "";
    }
    inMessage.put(Message.PATH_INFO, contextPath + req.getPathInfo());
    ....
    ....
}
```

What problem of our system and how can I do to resolve this problem ?
Is there any reported bugs on CXF's ServletDestination ?

You can add a comment if you need any additional information.

Best regards.

Comment: Did you run performance profiles/traces on the various systems. It could be network, it could be software, it could be a slow disk. There is not much to go on here.

Comment: This CXF version is quiet old and no longer supported. Have you tried to upgrade to a more recent release?